# Artificial neural network hyperparameter tuning to decide optimal neural network taking too long to return results

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, gridsearchcv

We have developed an Artificial Neural Network in Python, and in that regard, we would like to tune the hyperparameters with GridSearchCV to find the best possible hyperparameters. The goal of our ANN is to predict the default credit card customers, as the results the code has been running for the last two weeks. Is there anything I need to add or remove from my code to run efficiently to return the results?
See the code below:

```
# coding: utf-8

# # Artificial Neural Network - Hyperparemter Tunning
# 
# For this notebook we aim to establish a benchmark artficial neural network for the UCI Taiwan Credit Data. We consider the architechture, weight initialisation, optimisation algorithms, activation function and the learning rate to achieve our objectives.

pip install -r requirements.txt

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import metrics
import tensorflow as tf
import os

from scipy.stats import skew, norm
from scipy.special import boxcox1p
from scipy.stats import boxcox_normmax

from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import InputLayer 
from keras.layers import Dense 
from keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adagrad
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adadelta
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
import joblib
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action="ignore")
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

curr_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("__file__")) # current notebook direction
data_dir = os.path.join(curr_dir,"Data/Credit Data1/UCI_Credit_Card.csv") # one up directory

data = pd.read_csv(data_dir)

data.head()


# <h2>Dataset Information</h2>
# 
# This dataset contains information on default payments, demographic factors, credit data, history of payment, and bill statements of credit card clients in Taiwan from April 2005 to September 2005.
# Content
# 
# <h4>There are 25 variables:</h4>
# <ul>
# <li>ID: ID of each client</li>
# <li>LIMIT_BAL: Amount of given credit in NT dollars (includes individual and family/supplementary credit</li>
# <li>SEX: Gender (1=male, 2=female)</li>
# <li>EDUCATION: (1=graduate school, 2=university, 3=high school, 4=others, 5=unknown, 6=unknown)</li>
# <li>MARRIAGE: Marital status (1=married, 2=single, 3=others)</li>
# <li>AGE: Age in years</li>
# <li>PAY_0: Repayment status in September, 2005 (-1=pay duly, 1=payment delay for one month, 2=payment delay for two months, … 8=payment delay for eight months, 9=payment delay for nine months and above)</li>
# <li>PAY_2: Repayment status in August, 2005 (scale same as above)</li>
# <li>PAY_3: Repayment status in July, 2005 (scale same as above)</li>
# <li>PAY_4: Repayment status in June, 2005 (scale same as above)</li>
# <li>PAY_5: Repayment status in May, 2005 (scale same as above)</li>
# <li>PAY_6: Repayment status in April, 2005 (scale same as above)</li>
# <li>BILL_AMT1: Amount of bill statement in September, 2005 (NT dollar)</li>
#     <li>BILL_AMT2: Amount of bill statement in August, 2005 (NT dollar)</li>
#     <li>BILL_AMT3: Amount of bill statement in July, 2005 (NT dollar)</li>
#     <li>BILL_AMT4: Amount of bill statement in June, 2005 (NT dollar)</li>
#     <li>BILL_AMT5: Amount of bill statement in May, 2005 (NT dollar)</li>
#     <li>BILL_AMT6: Amount of bill statement in April, 2005 (NT dollar)</li>
#     <li>PAY_AMT1: Amount of previous payment in September, 2005 (NT dollar)</li>
#     <li>PAY_AMT2: Amount of previous payment in August, 2005 (NT dollar)</li>
#     <li>PAY_AMT3: Amount of previous payment in July, 2005 (NT dollar)</li>
#     <li>PAY_AMT4: Amount of previous payment in June, 2005 (NT dollar)</li>
#     <li>PAY_AMT5: Amount of previous payment in May, 2005 (NT dollar)</li>
#     <li>PAY_AMT6: Amount of previous payment in April, 2005 (NT dollar)</li>
#     <li>default.payment.next.month: Default payment (1=yes, 0=no)</li>
# </ul>


data.info()

data.isnull().sum()

data.drop('ID',1,inplace=True)

data.nunique()

x = data.drop(['default.payment.next.month'], axis=1)
y = data['default.payment.next.month']


# We decide on standardizing the data as a preprocessing step. This will allow us to give equal weight to all variables and not have our modelling destorted by the different scales between fields. And we split the data on a 67/33 split between traing and testing data, resulting in 20100 rows for training and 9900 for testing data. 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=8)
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test) 


# To get a clearer understanding we refer to the following [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/grid-search-hyperparameters-deep-learning-models-python-keras/). For this exercise we focus hyperparamter tunning for an Artificial Neural Network (ANN). The aim for this exercise is to get the best tuned ANN to get a benchmark model. We will focus on the following paramters:
# <ul>
#     <li>Architechture - Number of Hidden layers</li>
#     <li>Architechture - Number of Neurons per hidden layer </li>
#     <li>Architechture - Configuration of neurons in each hidden layer </li>
#     <li>Weight Initialization</li>
#     <li>Learning rate and Momentum</li>
#     <li>Optimisation Algorithm</li>
#     <li>Batch Size and Epoch</li>
#     <li>Activation Function</li>
# </ul>

# ### Choosing the right combination.
# 
# For this part of the experiment we choose an approach that allows us to choose the a combination with the highest accuracy for the following parameters:
# <ul>
#     <li>Number of hidden layers</li>
#     <li>Number of neuron for all hidden layers</li>
#     <li>Activation function</li>
#     <li>Optimsation Algorithm</li>
#     <li>Weight initialisation</li>
# </ul>
# We send the paramters tthough a grid search for the paraters above and observe the mean accuracy for each of the combination and pick the best one.

def create_model(init_mode='uniform',neurons=1,hidden_layers=1,optimizer='adam',activation ='relu',learning_rate=0.01):
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(neurons, input_dim=23, kernel_initializer=init_mode, activation='tanh'))
    for i in range(hidden_layers):
        # Add one hidden layer
        model.add(Dense(neurons, activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer=init_mode, activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    if optimizer=='Adam':
        optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
    elif optimizer=='SGD':
        SGD(learning_rate=0.01)
    elif optimizer=='Adadelta':
        Adadelta(learning_rate=0.01)
    elif optimizer=='Adagrad':
        Adagrad(learning_rate=0.01)
    
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model)
# define the grid search parameters
activation = ['softmax', 'tanh', 'sigmoid','relu']
optimizer = ['SGD','Adadelta', 'Adagrad','Adam']
init_mode = ['uniform', 'lecun_uniform', 'glorot_uniform', 'he_uniform']
neurons = [6,12,24,48]
hidden_layers = [1,2,3,4,5]
learning_rate = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2]
batchSize = [5,10,32,64]
epochs = [10,25,50,100]
param_grid = dict(init_mode=init_mode,neurons=neurons,optimizer=optimizer,
                  activation=activation,hidden_layers =hidden_layers,learning_rate = learning_rate,
                 batch_size=batchSize, epochs=epochs)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=2)

grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

yprednn=grid_result.predict(X_test)
yprednn=yprednn.round()
print('Neural Network:\n {}\n'.format(
    metrics.classification_report(yprednn, y_test)))
nn_conf_matrix=metrics.confusion_matrix(yprednn,y_test)
conf_mat_nn = pd.DataFrame(
    nn_conf_matrix, 
    columns=["Predicted NO", "Predicted YES"], 
    index=["Actual NO", "Actual YES"]
)
print(conf_mat_nn)
# summarize results
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))


# Looking at the classification report we can see that the overall accuracy of the model sits at 82\%. We must also consider the reacl and precision for the class of interest '1'. And in this we note we identify 38\% of the a of defaults are predicted accuractely and 67\% of all defaults in our testing data set were picked up by our model. The F-score for this class is 49\%. 

joblib.dump(grid.best_params_, 'ANN Model.pkl', compress = 1)

model_json = classifier.to_json()
with open("saved-model/model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
    
classifier.save_weights("saved-model/model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")


# ### Combination on the number of neurons per hidden layer
# 
# The number of neurons for the hidden layers is always assumed to be equal. We test whether if we change this configuration we get better prediction accuracy. We consdier the following number of neurons for each hidden layer \[6,6,6,6\],\[6,6,12,12\],\[12,12,6,6\] and \[12,6,12,6\].

# Function to create model,for KerasClassifier
def create_my_model(neurons=[6,6,6,6]):
    #defining my model
    mymodel = Sequential()
    mymodel.add(Dense(neurons[0],input_dim=23, activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
    mymodel.add(Dense(neurons[1],kernel_initializer='uniform',activation='relu'))
    mymodel.add(Dense(neurons[2],kernel_initializer='uniform',activation='relu'))
    mymodel.add(Dense(neurons[3],kernel_initializer='uniform',activation='relu'))
    mymodel.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile the model
    mymodel.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return mymodel

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_my_model,batch_size = 5, epochs = 100)
neurons = [[6,6,6,6],[12,12,6,6],[6,6,12,12],[12,6,12,6]]
parameter_grid = dict(neurons=neurons)

mygrid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=parameter_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=5)
grid_result = mygrid.fit(X_train, y_train)

yprednn=grid_result.predict(X_test)
yprednn=yprednn.round()
print('Neural Network:\n {}\n'.format(
    metrics.classification_report(yprednn, y_test)))
nn_conf_matrix=metrics.confusion_matrix(yprednn,y_test)
conf_mat_nn = pd.DataFrame(
    nn_conf_matrix, 
    columns=["Predicted NO", "Predicted YES"], 
    index=["Actual NO", "Actual YES"]
)
print(conf_mat_nn)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is simply too many parameters in your ANN. How long has it been running for now? I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: The code has been running for two weeks now. I have 9 parameters with 4 levels each.

Comment: I think because you have two create my model functions, your code is somehow getting confused and switching between them and that's why it has taken two weeks with no results. Maybe change the second function to a different name and try again. I hope this helps :)

Comment: The first one is named "create_model" and the second one is "create_my_model"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).